# Kotlin : Mono<MutableList<Object>> don't return as dto when i put to ResultDto

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, reactive-programming

I need modify .block() repository database operations to without .block() -» just put request to stream not to memory.
When the results return simple entity or just something list is ok!
But when I return combined dto I get this:

```
{
    "resultsLength": 1,
    "results": {
        "scanAvailable": true
    }
}
```

Mapped dto to response

```
data class CustomObjectResultDto(
    val resultsLength: Long?,
    @JsonInclude
    val results: Mono<MutableList<CustomObjectDto>>
)
```

JsonFormat:

```
Want:

{
    "resultsLength": 1,
    "results": {

        "id": "61953fb7e85fe0605c00bdd1",
        "cardRequestDate": "2029-02-05T23:00:00Z",
        "userName": "XYZ",
        "applicationType": {
            "name": "plastic",
            "label": "plastic_label"
        },
        "status": {
            "name": "accepted",
            "label": "accepted_label"
        },
        "statusChangeDate": "2019-02-10T23:00:00Z",
        "virtualCardNumber": 157426399
    }    
}
Get:

{
    "resultsLength": 1,
    "results": {
        "scanAvailable": true
    }
}
```

Repository:

```
  override fun listing(ctx: context, filterParams: FilterParams, filterConfig: FilterConfig):
            Mono<MutableList<CustomObject>> {
        val sort = Sort.by(Sort.Direction.fromString(filterConfig.order), filterConfig.orderBy)
        val pageRequest = PageRequest.of(filterConfig.pageIndex, filterConfig.pageLimit, sort)
        val userInfoWithoutUser = context(
            partnerId = ctx.partnerId,
            correlationId = ctx.correlationId
        )
        val query =
            createQuery(userInfoWithoutUser, filterParams).collation(Collation.of(DEFAULT_COLLATION)).with(pageRequest)
        return reactiveMongoTemplate.find(query, CustomObject::class.java).collectList()
    }
```

Service:

```
 override fun listing(
        ctx: context,
        filterConfig: FilterConfig,
        filterParams: FilterParams
    ): CustomObjectResultDto {
        val result = repository.listing(ctx, filterParams, filterConfig)
            .flatMapIterable { list: List<CostumObject> ->
                list.map { it.toItemDto() }
            }.collectList()
        val count = repository.count(ctx, filterParams)

        return CustomObjectResultDto(count,result)
    }
```

Controller:

```
...
): MutableHttpResponse<CustomObjectResultDto> {
        val ctx = context(partnerId, userId, correlationId)
      ...log...
        val filterParams = FilterParams(userName, applicationType, status, wifiStatus, cardNumber)
        val filterConfig = FilterConfig(pageLimit, pageIndex, PAGE_ORDER_BY_VALUES.getValue(orderBy), order)
        return HttpResponse.ok(service.listing(ctx, filterConfig, filterParams))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved

```
override fun listing(
        ctx: context,
        filterConfig: FilterConfig,
        filterParams: FilterParams
    ): Mono<CustomObjectResultDto> {
        val count = repository.count(ctx, filterParams)
        return repository.listing(ctx, filterParams, filterConfig)
            .flatMapIterable { list: List<CustomObject> ->
                list.map { it.toItemDto() }
            }.collectList()
            .map { listOfDocuments ->
                CustomObjectResultDto(count, listOfDocuments)
            }
    }
```